# Parsing response from edge and identifying local system that a specific response has come

Tags: powershell, google-chrome-extension, registry, microsoft-edge

Requirement :
Step 1:
In microsoft edge, listen to a particular type of response being received and parse the response.
Step 2:
We are interested in one attribute from response and notify this attribute value to the local system.
Step 3:
Local windows system has to make changes in registry based on what value was received.

Question : I don't know how will microsoft edge notify local system about the attribute value. I initially thought of writing an extension who will wait for the response and on receiving it, parse the response and notify system but don't know how it will notify.

I tried exploring the path of using a powershell script to run in an extension and make changes in a specific registry key. But since extension cannot run a powershell script, this approach will not work.

I am out of ideas as to what will work

Comment: Extension can start a powershell script via `nativeMessaging`.